# df.to_sql suddently giving error about column not allowing nulls

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am having a bit of a strange issue.

I have a python script that appends a dataframe to a sql table.

I have been running this script for months without issue, but suddenly it is giving me issues about a particular column not being able to insert due to null values.

The problem is, there are no null or na values in the dataframe.

The table I am inserting into has an identity ID column, but this has never been an issue in the past... I am struggling to understand what might be going on here, any advice would be appreciated, code I am using is below.

```
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER= 
    servername; DATABASE=databasename;   Trusted_Connection=yes')
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
   df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Error message is as follows:

> IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Column_Name', table 'databasename.dbo.table'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

Actual lines showing on the error message:

[SQL: INSERT INTO [Schedule] ([Asset_ID], [Part_ID], [Shift_ID], [Quantity], [Containers], [SortOrder], [Status_ID], [ProductionDate], [CreatedDate]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ((84, 348, 1, 30, 21, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (84, 348, 4, 30, 21, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (84, 348, 7, 30, 10, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (79, 335, 7, 10, 42, 2, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (79, 335, 10, 10, 71, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (79, 336, 10, 56, 1, 2, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (79, 336, 13, 56, 10, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (26, 278, 1, 30, 54, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000))  ... displaying 10 of 264 total bound parameter sets ...  (55, 248, 10, 90, 2, 1, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)), (55, 248, 10, 90, 6, 4, 7, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 8, 51, 44, 565000)))]

Comment: What have you done to see if there are `None` values in `df`?

Comment: df[df.isna().any(axis = 1)]

df.column_name.unique()

exporting dataframe to clipboard and manually looking, etc.

Comment: From what I see, you are not inserting anything into column named `Column_Name` in the table which gives you the error. So what do you expect sql-server to put there other than NULL?

Comment: Column_Name was the example, the actual column is Shift_ID

Comment: Are there any columns in the table that are *not* included in the DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, two columns that allow nulls and the identity column. I want to emphasize that I was able to insert this way for weeks without issue, almost seems like there was some kind of sudden software change or something.

Comment: If this worked before, then there are two possibilities. 1. Change on your side: there is a value in `Shift_Id` in your dataframe that is unlike what you sent before and is being treated as or converted to a database `null`. 2: Change on the database side: the column was nullable and this was changed (though that is unlikely: I would want to murder any DBA that did that unannounced).

Answer (score 1):

So this ended up being a data integrity issue, completely unrelated to having null rows.

Essentially one table had two IDs referring to basically the same thing, one of which is apparently obsolete. The obsolete item was erroring out when trying to upload due to other constraints.